# ionic cordova build iOS --release fails

Tags: ios, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to publish my ionic app to the app store and create a release version of the app.  Whenever I run `ionic cordova build iOS --release` I get the following console error.

```
(node:14365) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn EACCES
    at _errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:340:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:499:9)
    at Object.exports.spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:134:31)
    at runScriptViaChildProcessSpawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:225:23)
    at runScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:166:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:132:20
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
(node:14365) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14365) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build ios --release (exit code 1).
```

Does anyone have a solution for this/Seen this issue?

Comment: the command you need to try is `ionic cordova build ios --prod --release`. not sure if that is the exact cause of your error

Comment: This ended up being a plugin that was did not have a required dependency